# Getting ASP.NET Core RC1, DNX & dnu on CI/build server after release of ASP.NET Core RTM

Tags: continuous-integration, dnx, legacy-code, dnu, .net-core-rc1

How do you get ASP.NET Core RC1, DNX & dnu on CI/build server now after the release of ASP.NET Core RTM - without installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (and letting it fetch the RC1 runtime) on the server?

Now that ASP.NET Core RTM is released, the RC2 stuff has been obsoleted, and the RC1 stuff has practically been removed. All the links here on SO are dead, all the methods are non-working, and all the RC1 download stuff on the ASP.NET GitHub repos is gone.

For RC2, it is simply a matter of installing the RC2 ASP.NET Core server bundle. But since DNX is retired, and dnu with it, all I can find is the Platform Handler that needs to be installed to run RC1 in IIS.

If anyone could help me with something concrete, I would be super happy.